# Orace/SQL multiple group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I can't seem to get my head around this...

I have the following statement:

```
select    aT.PieceNo, count(*)
from      send_piece aT 
where     message_no in (7104, 7113)
and       aT.Created > To_Timestamp('01-JAN-14 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')
group by  aT.PieceNo;
```

In this grouped list, there will be many records with the same PieceNo AND aT.Created value. I need to show only these records.

I tried

```
group by  aT.PieceNo, aT.Created;
```

but it seemed to reverse the initial grouping.

Table structured as follows: ID, Message_No, XML_Data, Created

I am extracting the PieceNo value from the XML_Data. The above query returns:

167408305E01    5

167408505C01    8

167408206A01    9

167408306A01    4

...

Each record within that group contains a Created value (DateTime). I need to show only the records that share the same Created value within those groups (if that makes sense?).

Basically, I'm trying to extract all the records in this table that share the same PieceNo and Created values.

Comment: What do you mean "reverse" the initial grouping??? you don't have a `ORDER BY` in your statement... are you trying to get the data back in a specific order?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and sample results?  Your description doesn't help me.

Comment: Apologies. Don't care about order, and I can't post an actual table extract... for a multitude of reasons. Chief of which; it being horrendously large.

Comment: Well you're grouping by a new column this will change the the return value. I'm not entirely sure what the issue is. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select    aT.PieceNo, aT.Created,count(*)
 from      send_piece aT 
 where     message_no in (7104, 7113)
 and       aT.Created > To_Timestamp('01-JAN-14 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')
 group by  aT.PieceNo, aT.Created;
```

Comment: not sure about ans.. if you not looking for this.. please add your desired result to question

Comment: When i tried this I lost the initial grouping. By this I mean i just ended up with a long list of individual records with only one count.

Comment: i think your table for the combination of aT.PieceNo, aT.Created contains only one value for the date>'01-JAN-14... nothing wrong in the query

Comment: @user1830285 What output are you looking for? Please provide an example.

Comment: :) you are exactly right Sai, apologies. When I expanded the query to include earlier months they started showing up. Schoolboy error. Thanks for your help guys

Comment: :) you confused every one